# Convert HTML to Excel Rich Text and vice versa

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) for transferring data between MySQL DB and Excel  2007 worksheets. It works well on most situations, but I encountered one problem.

Some of the fields in DB contain HTML data. I need to preserve the formatting in Excel cells as much as possible. As I could figure out, Excel allows the following formatting inside cells (`PHPExcel_RichText` class supports all of these): new lines [these can be used to track `<p></p>` blocks], font name, size, color, bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, subscript, superscript. Suppose these are enough, so we can ignore other HTML formatting.

What is the best (easiest, fastest) way to convert HTML data to Excel Rich Text and vice versa?

One solution I've in mind is to create a function that will traverse the HTML [using `DOMDocument` or so], place `\n` after block elements, create `PHPExcel_RichText_Run` objects for `<b>`, `<i>` etc, and ignore all other elements. I feel this will be quite "expensive", especially when dealing with nested structures, like `<b>some <i>formatted<i> text</b>`

Is there any better way to do this, with or without `PHPExcel`?

One more idea: I noticed that when exporting in *XML Spreadsheet 2003* format the following appears inside XML:

```
<ss:Data ss:Type="String"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Font html:Color="#000000">this is </Font><B><Font
    html:Color="#000000">some </Font><I><Font html:Color="#000000">formatted</Font></I><Font
    html:Color="#000000"> text</Font></B></ss:Data>
```

which is normal HTML4. I mean it seems that Excel **can** understand plain HTML. So maybe there is some way to pass HTML directly to Excel without converting it to `PHPExcel_RichText` objects... (although note that it would be best if I'll be able to export to .xlsx format)

Comment: If found this [link](http://unableresolve.com/convert-html-to-excel-rich-text-and-vice-versa-141371.html) that seems to be a copy from the answer above - strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML to Rich-Text Runs is on the PHPExcel development roadmap for the coming year: however, the planned method was to use DOMDocument to parse the markup.

Any solution that we adopt for PHPExcel itself will have to use RichText Runs to provide consistency. While MS Excel itself can handle direct imports of Excel, and (as you've noted in the SpreadSheetML xml format offered by Excel 2003), this isn't consistent across the other different Excel formats (BIFF and OfficeOpenXML).

Comment: Thanks! So can you confirm that there is no better way to convert HTML to .xlsx using the current version of PHPExcel ? I mean, the answer to my question (if it exists) should be searched "outside" PHPExcel ...

Comment: None at the moment... an HTML Reader is on the roadmap, as is a helper method for converting a block of HTML to a Rich Text Run that can be written cleanly by the Writers... the helper method will be available sooner, but not until Q2 2012, and HTML Reader will probably be Q2 but may slip into Q3. I'd planned on using DOMDocument (the initial work I've done is all DOMDocument-based), though locating <br /> using DOMDocument is a real pain (which is why it's not yet available). Excel2003XML Writer will also certainly be Q3.

Comment: Mark, can I see the PHPExcel source codes or even contribute to them? it seems it will be better if I use PHPExcel's solution instead of reinventing a wheel... maybe i'll be able to help to deliver this functionality earlier

Comment: PHPExcel is fully open source: if you download it from the site - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets -  you're downloading the PHP source... and the basic HTML reader is about 70% complete (it's missing the HTML -> Rich Text helper at the moment)