# Render excel worksheet in html, using php, including rich text and hyperlinks

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I'm looking for a way to read an excel file (xls format, but could probably use xlsx if necessary), and convert that file into an html table, preserving the rich text in the cells, cell borders, as well as the hyperlinks.

I've looked at https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader2/, which looks pretty good except some borders are missed and hyperlink targets have missing letter at end of filename (weird).  I could probably debug these if I have to, but another problem with this is that this code base isn't supported any more.  See http://www.steeplechasers.org/racecalendar-php-excel.php for example (spreadsheet is at http://www.steeplechasers.org/racecalendar.xls ).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("racecalendar.xls");
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.excel {
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:1;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
table.excel thead th, table.excel tbody th {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:1;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
table.excel tbody th {
    text-align:center;
    width:20px;
}
table.excel tbody td {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
table.excel tbody td {
    padding: 0 3px;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $data->dump(true,true); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I also looked at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel, which seems like it should be able to do this somehow, but using simple generateSheetData, borders rich text and hyperlinks don't seem to be preserved, and I'm having trouble groking the docs to see how to copy these attributes into html.  See http://www.steeplechasers.org/racecalendar-PHPExcel.php for example (same input file).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$filename = 'racecalendar.xls';
//$filetype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filename);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$excel = $reader->load($filename);
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "HTML");
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
<?php
echo $writer->generateStyles(false);
?>
</style>

<body>
<?php
echo $writer->generateSheetData();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[Convert HTML to Excel Rich Text and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044708/convert-html-to-excel-rich-text-and-vice-versa) seems to indicate this isn't a feature of PHPExcel yet.

[PHPExcel - Preserve rich text format on import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405525/phpexcel-preserve-rich-text-format-on-import) didn't answer the question at all, as far as I could tell.

Is there another way to do this directly, or some way to do this with PHPExcel?

NOTE: I would actually like to iterate through the cells because I want to add a column to the html table as I go -- I used code to dump the whole spreadsheet as simple examples of the package behaviors, and this is as far as I have gotten in my investigation.

Comment: Why are you setting generateStyles(false);

Comment: @MarkBaker I copied example from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md (search for generateStyles) -- seems false means not to create <style></style> tags.

Comment: But you are developer for PHPOffice, right?  Is there an API document for this?  Maybe (false) means something else?

Comment: Yes I am the PHPExcel developer, and yes there are API docs provided as part of the standard distribution, generated using PHPDocumentor - http://sivers.su/doc/phpexcel/packages/PHPExcel.html

Comment: PHPExcel should certainly maintain borders and Rich text in the HTML Writer, but not if you set `generateStyles(false);`

Comment: Thanks for the API spec.  I removed <style></style> tags, and used generateStyles(true) but got same results.  See http://www.steeplechasers.org/racecalendar-PHPExcel-v2.php .  Note I'm using version 1.8.0.  Should I be using develop branch?

Comment: I have the answer.... see below

Comment: Temporary fix for PHPExcel's URL links added to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting

```
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

when you read the spreadsheet file

This tells PHPExcel to ignore any formatting information in the spreadsheet file, and only to read the raw data in the cells. It means that all formatting (borders, number formatting styles, font colours, etc) will be ignored

The solution is not to set `$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);`

**EDIT**

As a quick `hack` for the URLs, you can modify `/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php`

Lines 4564 and 4565

```
$url = self::_encodeUTF16(substr($recordData, $offset, $us - 2), false);
$url .= $hasText ? '#' : '';
```

change to

```
$url = self::_encodeUTF16(substr($recordData, $offset, $us - 2), false);
$nullOffset = strpos($url, 0x00);
if ($nullOffset)
    $url = substr($url,0,$nullOffset);
$url .= $hasText ? '#' : '';
```

It fixes the URLs (note that php-excel-reader2 loses the last character of the URL) by testing for a null string terminator; and doesn't appear to have any adverse effects though it isn't adjusting the offset to allow for the adjustment. I need to check the BIFF specs and run a few more tests against both BIFF 5 and BIFF8 files with different link types before I'll commit anything back to the github repo)

Comment: This is much closer -- see http://www.steeplechasers.org/racecalendar-PHPExcel-v3.php .  The rich text and borders are present perfectly. I read the method as "set data read only" -- duh.  But unfortunately the hyperlinks have garbled data at the end of the filename and don't work.  Is this a bug or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also is there a way to iterate through each cell?  That's my preference as I want to add a column to the html table which is not in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Garbled hyperlinks could be a bug, but I'd have to set up some tests to check

Comment: Really appreciate your help.  If you want me to log an issue, please let me know.

Comment: You can iterate cells within a row using the iterators (see `/Examples/28iterator.php' for an example of how to use iterators.) You can also populate a column directly using the worksheet's `fromArray()` method, or individual cells.

Comment: Thanks for the hack, and for the pointer to how to iterate through the cells.  I'll check the URL hack out tomorrow, and the iteration in the coming days.  Again, really appreciate the quick response / support.

Comment: The hack seems to work.  Note it replaced lines 4563-4564 in the version 1.8.0 I'd downloaded.  See http://www.steeplechasers.org/racecalendar-PHPExcel-v3.php for working version.

Comment: I've looked at the iterator example, and at http://sivers.su/doc/phpexcel/classes/PHPExcel_Writer_HTML.html but don't see how to generate the HTML for a single cell.  Also does this include the <td> tag?  What if cell is in header? (I need first row to be header and I need to add cells for new first column).  Possibly you are suggesting I insert the column into the worksheet first, then generateSheetData()?  This will work but still need to have header.

Comment: You shouldn't need to generate the HTML for a cell, it's the job of the HTML Writer to generate the HTML for cells; to add a new column or row, you'd add it to the PHPExcel object. If you want to change the way that the HTML Writer generates its output to include additional content, then you'd need to modify the code for that Writer.

Comment: Ok, I think I can probably add the extra column to the PHPExcel object, then generate the html using generateSheetData() to a variable, then modify the html as required (i.e., to use <thead><th> tags for the first row, required by datatables JQuery package) using something like http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php .  I was hoping I could trick PHPExcel into generating the header row, but seems like I can probably find another way.  Thanks for your support and for your package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that might help: [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/put-excel-data-on-a-web-page-HP005256150.aspx).

Also, you can get the XML version of Excel (Excel is stored as XML I believe) and then just analyze the XML with PHP and put in a table on your website. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is the process we are using now, or a similar one. But we want to render the page without all the fiddling with the excel file output.  Also note this is xls file (preferred), not in xml like xlsx file.

Comment: @Lou I don't think that's possible with plain HTML and PHP. Users might need to have a plugin to be able to view Excel files strait from the browser (like PDF needs Adobe Reader plugin).

Comment: Please look at examples in OP. The first one is close. I'm trying to read xls, but render html table. I think it's possible with the right php code. php-excel just has a couple of bugs.